# Dynamic content on cached product page?

Tags: php

There is an ecommerce app with fully cached product page using Memcached. So a controller checks by the key if the page is cached. If cached it takes 1,5 ms to output html from memory.

```
$product_rendered = $this->cache->get($key);
if(empty($product_rendered)) {
 //$product ... Get data for product
 $this->cache->set($key, $product, 86400);
}
```

But now there is a dynamic content which changes every 15 minutes on site. Delivery terms, product availability, shipping costs, etc.

*The question is how to change that dynamic info in cached content when a user loads page?*

Don't want to use AJAX on page load.
It can be done by replacing substring in cached product_info ($product_rendered) like:

```
$output = sprintf($product_rendered, $dynamic_content);
```

Maybe there is a better choice?

Comment: If you switch to varnish for caching, ESI can be used. https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/esi.html

Comment: @Kaspars, very interesting, but not what I'm seraching for :)